# Se oculta automaticamente mi Modal, bootstrap, alguien sabe como solucionar el problema sin tener que cambiar la etiquera <a> ..?

Tags: bootstrap

[image]
Parte de mi código, quisiera no tener que remplazar la etiqueta , alguien tiene una solución?

Comment: Varias cosas a tener en cuenta: 1) Las imágenes con código no sirven de mucho pues no podemos copiar ese código para nuestras pruebas. Puedes [edit] la pregunta para quitar esa imagen y ponerlo en modo texto. 2) No has puesto todo el código, apenas se ve el código del modal 3) Tu pregunta no se entiende (al menos yo no la entiendo). ¿que quieres decir con que se oculta automáticamente?  ¿al pulsar fuera del modal?  Eso es lo normal, pero se puede modificar con [esto](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.1/components/modal/#static-backdrop)

Comment: Si, perdón, al presionar el botón para agregar y aparezca el modal , al poco tiempo se cierra solo, si modifico la etiqueta a , le pongo por ejemplo un button funciona , pero quisiera mantener el diseño de la etiqueta sin que se cierre

Comment: En el cacho de código de la imagen no se ve cómo llamas al modal.  Tampoco se ve cual de los enlaces **<a>** lo llama.  Eso que dices que desaparece no es lo habitual, por eso sería necesario que pusieras bien todo el codigo necesario para poder reproducir tu error y así poderte ayudar mejor.